# how to display middle element to top from ng-repeat loop list?

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to display middle element from the list to top from ng-repeat,what i have code for this is as below

```
<tr ng-repeat="(key, value) in schema" ng-if="value && !(key==='columns')">
                <td>{{key}}</td>
                <td ng-if="isString(value)">
                {{value | date:'medium'}}</td>
                <td ng-if="isObject(value)">
                <div ng-repeat="(key1, value1) in value">
                <p ng-if="key1==='id'"><a ui-sref='details({ Id: value1 })'> {{ guidName }} </a></p>
                <p class="sm-txt2"><b>{{ key1}} :  </b>
                {{ value1 | date:'medium'}}</p>
                </div>
                </td>
                </tr>
```

i want to display key==name to the top so what can i should do for this results

thanks,

for example,

```
  <tr ng-repeat="no in arraylist">
                <td>{{no}}</td>
  </tr>
```

arraylist may have 10 elements which is 1,2..5..10. 
what i want result is 5,1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9,10.

Comment: your question is not clear, you can provide the current data and sample output so we can understand better

Comment: it display output like this

Comment: there are to ng-repeat loops in wsich one you are talking?

Comment: create time,db,description,name,owener name

Comment: so i want.....name,create time,db,decription

Comment: Edit your question and explain, with a concrete example, what "display middle element from the list to top" means.

Comment: means for example......we have 10 elements in the ng-repeat serially(1 to 10) and i want 5 in the top

Comment: that is 5th element i want to show on the top

Comment: Edit your question, by clicking the "edit" link. Don't post comments. Why don't you simply change the order of the elements in the array in the controller? The view should not handle this.